Melpa packages not loading
My init.el file looks like this:
(require 'package)
'(package-archives
   '(("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t
     ("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize)

When I start emacs, the resulting Messages buffer contains:
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:443
Package refresh done
Contacting host: elpa.nongnu.org:443
Package refresh done
You can run the command ‘package-refresh-contents’ with M-x pa-co
Package refresh done

and no Melpa packages are available in the package list. I've tried multiple forms of the package-archives statement to no effect. I've seen this post, which doesn't provide any information beyond what's above. What stupid thing am I doing?

The second form should read: (setq package-archives '(("melpa" . ...))). The truncated form you show seems to be a copy from a customization file, where it is normally enclosed in a (custom-set-variables ...).
